# Error 405 Method Not Allowed when trying to POST

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring, http

I am trying to make a `http.post` from my service to my controller, but apparently it won't let that happen.

Service

```
export class CarServiceService {

  private usersUrl: string;

  readonly httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN": "http://localhost:4200",
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS": "true"
    })
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.usersUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
  }
  public save(car: Car) {
    return this.http.post(this.usersUrl+'/api/car/create-car', car, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/car")
public class CarController {

    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CarController(CarRepository carRepository) {

        this.carRepository = carRepository;
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/create-car", method = POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public void addCars(@RequestBody final car car) {
        this.carRepository.save(car);
    }
```

Comment: is this a `spring-boot` app? Are you sure the controller is registered as a spring bean?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos yes this is a spring-boot app. Angular/TS frontend, spring/java backend. However I thought that the `RestController ` annotation would suffice

Comment: share please with us the package structure that you have

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-car", method = POST)
```

with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-car", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

or

```
@PostMapping("/create-car")
```

Comment: Tried both, no change

Comment: And the parameter `car` in the service is set and not `null`? And the object `Car` is exactly the same in the frontend and backend?

Comment: I just checked, everything is set and they are the same in front and backend. I did also find out that when I try to use the `GET` method in the controller, it responds with a `Error 500`. Mhh...

Comment: Why you define the `car` as `final`? Just write `@RequestBody Car car`

Comment: True, changed it. Didn't solve the issue but thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: And why you have defined the annotation `@ResponseBody`? This controller returns nothing (`void`): remove this also…

Comment: And at least, in the frontend, the `http.post` request returns a observable, what means, this only activate with the `subscribe()`-method.